# ImportXML function format data in spreadsheet

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, formatting, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import some live match data from XML feed using the ImportXML function and that's how it looks when it runs:

[image: importXML data in cells]

Basically 2 rows = 1 match (Spain is playing with Italy, Everton with Liverpool, etc.).
Teams listing is the first ImportXML function in A1. The score is another ImportXML function located in B1.
I can't manage to move the blue fields to the orange spot, so both teams are in one row (1 match per row).
Do I have to create separate ImportXML for every match or something? I have no idea.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiYrkv5aSrfmdHQ1b19ORm1TODdBcUFpVk1MQjlSMHc&usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Comment: may we have some complementary informations: URL / Raw data / XML formula you wrote? I believe it will improve subsequently your chances to have an answer

Comment: oh sorry, here's the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiYrkv5aSrfmdHQ1b19ORm1TODdBcUFpVk1MQjlSMHc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to do it with 4 formulas (one in each column). [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao02g19G1-G-dHp3TlM0a01HbDdaWjh2bU9oRXc3QVE&usp=sharing) the demo. and bellow the explainations:
You need to look for the first or the second value of the node you are interested. For that, I just modified a little the XML. Request for the first country it's:

```
=ImportXML("http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/soccer/events/top?_accept=text/xml&apikey=9nrqbfsah2m6sprwtntth3kv";"//competitors/competitorsItem[1]/team/name")
```

As you can see I added `[1]` just after `competitorsItem`. So I limit the results to only the first occurence. Then on the fourth column I do the same but I changed `[1]` for `[2]` to get the opponent country.
I found the documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

I hope it will be something usefull for you.

Harold

**EDIT**

you'll find [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao02g19G1-G-dHp3TlM0a01HbDdaWjh2bU9oRXc3QVE&usp=sharing#gid=1) a variant of the previous demo where you get all the results at once.
the formula is:

```
=ImportXML("http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/soccer/events/top?_accept=text/xml&apikey=9nrqbfsah2m6sprwtntth3kv","//competitors/competitorsItem[2]/score|//competitors/competitorsItem[2]/team/name|//competitors/competitorsItem[1]/score|//competitors/competitorsItem[1]/team/name")
```

But of course you are then forced to remix them. For that I used an array formula:

```
={index(A:A;(row()-1)*4+2),index(A:A;(row()-1)*4+1),index(A:A;(row()-1)*4+3),index(A:A;(row()-1)*4+4)}
```

Comment: but if I use this function 4 times, won't it lag the website, because of 4x xml file download request? I thought there is an option to download file first, parse it locally and put into collumns, without dividing it into 4 separate requests.

Comment: @VixinG Updated the formula to perform a one shot import